# Django - cannot retrieve just one record in multi-part filter on model with multiple relations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I can't seem to isolate a single record from this query:

```
subcust = OwnerCustom.objects.get(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset)
```

This is the error:

```
OwnerCustom matching query does not exist
```

In the actual data, there is only actually one matching record in OwnerCustom for each record in CarCustom. It's supposed to be a kind of many-to-many where there are standard differences listed in CarCustom for each Car, and each owner may maintain their own customizations (overrides) or those default OwnerCustom entries.

Note, there are many different Owner of the same Car. And of course, I'm not actually doing cars, this is a renaming from the original purpose.

Here's the relevant models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car_name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CarCustom(models.Model):    
    car         = models.ForeignKey(Car, models.PROTECT)

class Owner(models.Model):
    car         = models.ForeignKey(Car, models.PROTECT)

class OwnerCustom(models.Model):
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(Owner, models.PROTECT)
    carcustom   = models.ForeignKey(CarCustom, models.PROTECT)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And the code:

```
car_queryset = Car.objects.filter(car_name="fancy car")
for nset in car_queryset:

    owner_queryset = Owner.objects.filter(car=nset)
    for sset in owner_queryset :

        carcustom_queryset = CarCustom.objects.filter(car=nset)
        for ncset in carcustom_queryset:
            subcust = OwnerCustom.objects.get(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset)
```

I've tried stuff like:

```
subcust = OwnerCustom.objects.filter(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset).first()
```

Which gives me a NoneType, and then tried:

```
subcust = OwnerCustom.objects.filter(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset)[:1].get()
```

Which gives "matching query does not exist" and this:

```
subcust = OwnerCustom.objects.filter(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset)[0]
```

Gives "list index out of range"

UPDATE: I CAN get a working function by using code like this, but I would think since there is only one (guaranteed by application) matching record possible for OwnerCustom.objects.filter(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset) that I could find a better way to fetch it:

```
car_queryset = Car.objects.filter(car_name="fancy car")
for nset in car_queryset:

    owner_queryset = Owner.objects.filter(car=nset)
    for sset in owner_queryset :

        carcustom_queryset = CarCustom.objects.filter(car=nset)
        for ncset in carcustom_queryset:
            subcust_queryset = OwnerCustom.objects.filter(carcustom=ncset, owner=sset)
            for subcust in subcust_queryset :
                logger.info(subcust.name)
```

Comment: Why are you trying first(), or [0]. The error OwnerCustom matching query does not exist means, there is no record in your OwnerCustom database table where carcustom=ncset and owner=sset. Are you sure about data present in your DB ?

Comment: And are you sure about the result return by each of your request ?

You can make all your request in one : OwnerCustom.objects.get(carcustom__car__car_name=="fancy car"), owner__car__car_name=="fancy car")

Comment: Yes, there is data in these tables that should qualify. I'll include code that does work to the end of my original question, but I don't think that code is the best way to handle the task.

Comment: Do you try my custom request ? [doc about related field in filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)